# can PIL open an image using pyqt4 resource file?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pyqt4, pyrcc

Can PIL open an image using pyqt4 resource file?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageWin
import res_rc #resource file

image = Image.open(":/images/image.png")
dim = ImageWin.Dib(image)
```

I'm getting this error

`IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename :/images/image.png'`

Comment: Can you get a file-like to the resource data?

Comment: I don't know either. If possible I just want to put the image to the pyqt4 resource file rather than separating it to an image file. So the user cannot edit or erase the image file.

Comment: It's pretty easy if you can get a file-like, so work on that first.

Comment: Do you literally mean from the resource file, or do you mean from the resource object code ? If the former, it is a simply matter of parsing a XML file. If the latter, you have access to PyQt modules, so load the resource using `QPixMap` and convert it to use with PIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read an image file from a resource, open it with a QFile and pass the raw data to a file-like object that can be used by PIL:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image, ImageWin
import res_rc

stream = QFile(':/images/image.png')
if stream.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
    data = stream.readAll()
    stream.close()
    image = Image.open(StringIO(data))
    dim = ImageWin.Dib(image)
```

Note that resources are designed to be *compiled into* the application, and so they are strictly read-only.